# Is it possible to access a parentclass-constructor not from the first line of a subclass-constructor?

Tags: java, constructor

For school I'm working on a system to handle audiofiles, some audifile-formats don't include meta data available to work with, in this case i want to just call the constructor of the superclass: "AudioFile" that does some string formatting to get attributes like "author" or "title" out of the filename. In the case of meta data being available, i want to execute a method called`readAndStoreTags()` which gets the mentioned attributes directly out of the files meta data.

This is how I want my code to be working on a logical level:

```
TaggedFile(String s) {
        try {
            readAndStoreTags(); //works with metda data of audiofile
        } catch(NullPointerException e) { //if unsuited audiofile-format --> can't access meta data --> throws "NullPointerException"
            super(s); //should then just call the constructor of the parentclass
        }
    }
```

The issue being obviously that `super(s)` can only be called at the first line of a constructor. If I just call `super(s)` before the Exception Handler and then create an instance of class `TaggedFile` with an unsuited  audiofile format, it just terminates.
Is there any way to call the parentclass constructor like in the code above? Or is there any other way for me to get around this issue?

Comment: "*Is it possible to access a parentclass-constructor not from the first line of a subclass-constructor?*" - No.

Comment: For details see [JLS, §8.8.7](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.8.7), which defines that an explicit constructor invocation must be the first statement of a constructor.